# SFML 2 Real Time Text Input?(No Event Loop)

Tags: c++, sfml

Im writing a SFML program were the main window is handled in the Window.cpp class. I also have a ScreenManager class that handles the different screens. In my newMapScreen class i need to get text input from the user to name a Map they are creating. I created a event loop by passing in the Window in this newMapScreen class but it registers events very slowly. The user has to hold down the button for 1+ seconds before the program can register the key entered. I need to get real time text input much like doing if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard:::Key)). Also is there any way i can use the keyboard without checking for every key on the keyboard? Anyway i can handle the textinput from the window class and acsess it in my newMapScreen class? Ik its a hard question to understand sorry guys.
Im currently getting the input like this:

```
   void newMapScreen::updateWithWindow(sf::RenderWindow &Window)
{
  while(Window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
       case sf::Event::TextEntered:
           if(onEnterMap)
            {
               if(event.text.unicode >= 32 && event.text.unicode <= 126)
                {
               mapNameS += (char)event.text.unicode;
                }else if(event.text.unicode == 8 && mapNameS.getSize() > 0)
                {
                  mapNameS.erase(mapNameS.getSize() -1, mapNameS.getSize());
                }
            }
           if(onMapSizeX)
            {

            }
           if(onMapSizeY)
            {

            }
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check `sf::event` first! Then check if it's a keyboard event.

Answer (score 0):

I threw this together as an example. It may not be the best way to do this, it's just an example.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500,500), "Text reader!");

    std::string s;

    while(window.isOpen()){

        //Event processing.
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered){
                if(event.KeyPressed == sf::Keyboard::BackSpace && s.size()!=0){
                    s.pop_back();
                    std::cout << s << std::endl;
                }
                else if (event.text.unicode < 128) {
                    s.push_back((char)event.text.unicode);
                    std::cout << s << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably! See: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-events.php, quote: 

_The member associated to this event is event.text, it contains the Unicode value of the entered character. You can either put it directly in a sf::String, or cast it to a char after making sure that it is in the ASCII range (0 - 127)._

Comment: This mixes `TextEntered` and `KeyPressed` events types handling, so it's wrong. If we assume `event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered`,  then the only valid member we may access is `event.text.unicode`.